# What is the difference between searchlogic and other fulltext search plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, heroku, searchlogic, xapian

I am looking for an alternative to acts_as_solr or thinkingsphinx for fulltext search in my Rails app. Came across searchlogic. Does it support indexing? I am planning to host my app on heroku and  I want an alternative because heroku charges for Websolr. I am aware of the alternative way of using texticle or acts_as_tsearch but i want to use searchlogic for its features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searchlogic supports searching by providing an assortment of ActiveRecord named scopes. It's not a full text search engine as Solr or Sphinx are.

- [Searchlogic Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/176-searchlogic)